# ios uiwebview how to embed qr scanner from webview

Tags: ios, webview

i have an `UIWebview` app in objective-c now my question is how do i allow this app for the `UIWebview` to access the camera and to scan a qr barcode?

i have found some code about how to access the camera to take photo's or videos, but don't see anything about scanning qr code. 
 is any example or advice where to look at?

Thank you in advance

Comment: thanks tom for helping to edit and ask the question the right way

Comment: I also have the same query, let me know if you found any solution for it.